# How to run main in android

Tags: java, android

Hi all i am writing simple app to train my ContentProvider skills .So i wrote Contract class that specifies all the meta data for all the tale her it is

```
public class StoreContract {

public static String AUTHORITY = "com.ura.store.intentProvider";
public static String DATABASE_NAME = "Store.db";

public static class Customer{
    public static final String TABLE_NAME ="tblCustomers";
    public static final String COLUMN_AUTO_ID = "_id";
    public static final String COLUMN_NAME="First Name";
    public static final String COLUMN_LAST_NAME = "Last name";
    public static final String COLUMN_PHONE_NUMBER = "Phone number";

    public static final String CREAT_STRING = "create table "+TABLE_NAME+
            " ( "+COLUMN_AUTO_ID+" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT , "
            +COLUMN_NAME+" TEXT , "
            +COLUMN_LAST_NAME+" TEXT , "
            +COLUMN_PHONE_NUMBER+" TEXT);"; 
}

static class Seller{
    public static final String TABLE_NAME = "tblEmployes";
    public static final String COLUMN_AUTO_ID = "_id";
    public static final String COLUMN_NAME="First Name";
    public static final String COLUMN_LAST_NAME = "Last name";
    public static final String COLUMN_EMPLOY_TYPE = "Type";
    public static final String CREAT_STRING = "create table "+TABLE_NAME+
            " ( "+COLUMN_AUTO_ID+" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT , "
            +COLUMN_NAME+" TEXT , "
            +COLUMN_LAST_NAME+" TEXT , "
            +COLUMN_EMPLOY_TYPE+" TEXT);"; 

}

static class Buy{
    public static final String TABLE_NAME = "tblBuys";
    public static final String COLUMN_AUTO_ID = "_id";
    public static final String COLUMN_CUSTOMER_ID = "Customer";
    public static final String COLUMN_SELLER_ID = "Seller";
    public static final String COLUMN_INFO = "Info";
    public static final String COLUMN_PRICE = "Price";
    public static final String CREAT_STRING = "create table "+TABLE_NAME+
            " ( "+COLUMN_AUTO_ID+" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT , "
            +COLUMN_CUSTOMER_ID+" TEXT, "
            +COLUMN_SELLER_ID+" TEXT , "
            +COLUMN_INFO+" TEXT "
            +COLUMN_PRICE+" REAL"
            +"FOREIGN KEY("+COLUMN_CUSTOMER_ID+") REFERENCES "+Customer.TABLE_NAME+"("+Customer.COLUMN_AUTO_ID+")"
            +"FOREIGN_KEY("+COLUMN_SELLER_ID+") REFERENCES "+Seller.COLUMN_AUTO_ID+"("+Seller.COLUMN_AUTO_ID+")";
}

public static void main(String []args){
    System.out.println(StoreContract.Customer.CREAT_STRING);
}
```

Notice the main method i wrote it to see how my Table creation String looks like of course the method didn't work probably be cause it is Android Project .So my question is simple what do you suggest to do in such cases i mean a except of copying and passing all class in to other project i am pretty sure that there  is a standard solution for this stuff some unit-test or something.
Thank :)

Answer (score 4):

The Android equivalent of the main method is [onCreate()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onCreate%28android.os.Bundle%29) in Activities (and pretty much everywhere else)

Comment: Thank you.But this is a simple class not an activity

Comment: @urag AFAIK android does not provide a way for you to put a "main" type method in an arbitrary class. The main objects capable of running code are Activity, Service, and BroadcastReceiver.

Comment: @urag Put it in the constructor then.

Comment: The lifetime cycle of an Android app is more complicated than start/finish. Also, it's a GUI system, and most of the time the app code is not running - it's waiting for a callback from a system to arrive. So the linear programming model that `main()` assumes does not really apply. Read up on [Android app lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fundamentals.html).

Answer (score 3):

Unlike pure java applications, Android apps will not call main() as their starting point, but instead the onCreate() method of their top level activity. This activity needs to be specified by name through `<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />` in the manifest section defining that activity.

To go about this, you would make a class that inherits from activity, add the code from your current main method in the onCreate() method, and access the class you have currently from there.

Also, there is a lot more to how android handles the lifespan of activities, and the method calls in them. I recommend [this link](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/starting.html) as a starting point to look into how android code runs.